# Comparing two sets of ratios

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, ratio

I am trying to choose the most appropriate test to use for comparison of two sets of ratios, with several replicates.

My data set is the number of male and female offspring, in two different scenarios. One situation has 19 replicates, the second situation has 34 replicates.

I want to test whether there is a statistic difference in the sex ratios (proportion of offspring that are male) between the two scenarios. Or to put it another way the sex ratio of 19 populations (with the same categorical explanatory variable x)  vs the sex ratio of 34 populations (with the same categorical explanatory variable y) - to see if populations with x have a different sex ratio to populations with y.

I have read that for sex ratio data, I should use Generalized Linear Models (glm) in r. This is because is because proportion data is bound between 0 and 1 and the data is likely to be non-normal.

However, I cannot find an example of a glm approach where the explanatory variable is categorical. It always seems to be used when the explanatory variable is continuous.

Can anybody help with suggesting an approach?